# Standard way to control symbol visibility

Tags: c++, c++14

Using C and plain functions in C++, I can prevent the functions' symbols to be exported by using `static` keyword:

```
static int foo(int a, int b) { /* ...  */ }
```

But in a class, defining a function as `static` has a completely different meaning. Is there a way to ensure the compiler that my whole class will be used only within module, and there is no need to export any of its methods' symbols?

Comment: Is there a reason exporting it is bad?

Comment: Dont' anonymous namespaces do this?

Comment: @MooingDuck I guess it adds some optimization freedom, when compiler is lacking a link-time optimization feature.

Comment: @Ivella: It's not about optimisation (even though that may be a side effect, I don't know), it's about not violating the ODR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an anonymous namespace.

```
namespace
{
    class C
    {
        C() {}
        void f() {}
    };

    void f();
}

class ExportedClass
{
    ExportedClass() {}
    void f() {}
};

void exportedFunction() {}
```

As you can see, you should do this for normal functions, too. The usage of `static` for this is discouraged.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the anonymous namespace. For example,

```
// file foo.cc
namespace {
    int symbol1 = 0;
    struct auxiliary { /* ... */ } symbol2;
}

void foo(int x)
{
  // uses symbol1 and symbol2
}
```

when `symbol1` and `symbol2` are not 'visible'.

Answer (score -4):

Depending on what you want and why you are doing it you could move the class into the .cpp file. This works for example if you are implementing a library. Have a look at the discussion at [Putting class declaration in .cpp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657528/putting-class-declaration-in-cpp-file)

To be more specific your class should go in it's own separate translation unit away from main and away from classes outside of your module.

Comment: My class declaration is already in  a `.cpp`, but AFIK, that doesn't change compiled symbol visibility (headers inclusions are preprocessed, so the compiler can't really know if the class definition was originally in a `.hpp` header or not). I believe your answer is wrong.

Comment: class definitions will only be visible in the cpp module so unless you include the cpp file in another translation unit then the symbols will not be visible. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c

Comment: That's only true at the compiler level, but not on the linker level, where identically named symbols in different translation units can violate the ODR.

Comment: If you were supplying a dynamic library for example I don't think that would be an issue. For a static linkage I guess so. My statements made too many assumptions. I didn't think it though fully and I moved from focus from avoid export to avoiding usage. My mistake. Thanks for your comments.